# What does "uR" mean in cout?

Tags: c++, cout

In the following C++ code, what does `uR` mean?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << uR"(Hello, world!)" << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Right here, right now it prints

> 0x55ad7e90b986

Comment: Looks to be indicating what kind of data the string contains. I don't think it's an aspect of `cout`.

Comment: Should mean that it's an unsigned raw string literal. The R normally means that it's a raw string literal, and the u normally means that the letters shall be of an unsigned type.

Comment: @Carl make it an answer. (And link to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal )

Comment: Or better yet, help me look for a dupe. :/

Comment: I know this has nothing to do with the question, but I find it silly to see a line that ends like `..." << '\n';`, why isn't it just `...\n";` instead?

Comment: Please look through the documentation on [string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). It is UTF-16 encoded raw string literal.

Comment: Whoops, sorry Carl. I swear I didn't steal! It takes forever to type on my phone.

Comment: @Carl Thanks, I'll try and find a C++ one though.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Yep sorry, went a little fast there

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yeah no problem, most important thing is that there is an answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) , the `R` indicates a raw string, while the `u` indicates that it's encoded in UTF-16. The two can be combined.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and your answer! I'll mark it in 8 minutes.

Comment: "_Search the page for "auto S8" to jump to the relevant line._" You could, instead, link [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) page on string literals, instead of msdn - it explains every possible string literal at the top of the page..

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Good find, thanks. I'll update the link.

Answer (score 0):

UTF16-encoded string. See this beautiful [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx)